# Java, Best way to make and place a loop for enemy waves in a game

Tags: java, oop

I am working on a OOP final project which is a text based survival game.  I am currently trying to finish it up by having the player enter how many enemies they would like to fight then it loops through it until the amount is met.  What would be the best route?  I want it so that enemies can be selected twice, but my partner wants to do a shuffle of the array because less work.

Mostly I am stuck on where and what kind of loop I should make and where should I place it.

This is some code in the main class.

```
Entity entity = new Entity();
        ArrayList<Entity> enemies = new ArrayList<>();
        EnemyList enemyList = new EnemyList();

        Entity troll = new Troll();
        troll.setName("Troll");
        enemyList.characters.add(troll);

        Entity imp = new Imp();
        imp.setName("Imp");
        enemyList.characters.add(imp);

        Entity knight = new Knight();
        knight.setName("knight");
        enemyList.characters.add(knight);

        Entity skeleton = new Skeleton();
        skeleton.setName("Skeleton");
        enemyList.characters.add(skeleton);


        Integer[] array = new Integer[enemyList.characters.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
        }

        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));


 for (int i = 0; i < enemyCount; i++) {

            for (Entity someEnemy : enemyList.characters) {

                System.out.println(enemyList.characters.get(array[i]));

                System.out.println(someEnemy.getName(entity) + "\n");
                System.out.println("A " + someEnemy.getName(entity) + " Appears! It has " + someEnemy.getHealth() + "HP");

                while (someEnemy.getHealth() > 0) {

                    int attack = character.getAttack();
                    System.out.println("You hit the " + someEnemy.getName(entity) + " for " + character.getAttack());
                    int monsterTotalHealth = someEnemy.setHealth(someEnemy.getHealth() - attack);
                    System.out.println(someEnemy.getName(entity) + " has " + monsterTotalHealth + "HP Left");
                    System.out.println("");

                    if (someEnemy.getHealth() > 0) {

                        System.out.println("The monster attacks back for " + someEnemy.getStrength());
                        int remainingHP = character.damageDelt(someEnemy.getStrength());
                        System.out.println("Your remaining health is " + remainingHP);
                        System.out.println("");
                        character.setHealth(character.getHealth());
                    }

                    if (character.isDead()) {

                        System.out.println("You have been defeated!");
                        System.exit(0);

                    } else if (someEnemy.getHealth() < 0) {
                        System.out.println("Fighting Next monster");

                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Entity class

```
public class Entity {

    private String name;
    private int health;
    private int level;
    private int vitality;
    private int strength;
    private int resistance;
    private int dexterity;
    private int endurance;
    private int intelligence;
    private int attack;

    public String getName(Entity someenemy) {
        return name;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public int getVitality() {
        return vitality;
    }

    public int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }

    public int getResistance() {
        return resistance;
    }

    public int getDexterity() {
        return dexterity;
    }

    public int getEndurance() {
        return endurance;
    }

    public int getIntelligence() {
        return intelligence;
    }

    public int getAttack() { return attack; }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
        return health;
    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public int setVitality(int vitality) {
        this.vitality = vitality;
        return vitality;
    }

    public void setStrength(int strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public void setResistance(int resistance) {
        this.resistance = resistance;
    }

    public void setDexterity(int dexterity) {
        this.dexterity = dexterity;
    }

    public void setEndurance(int endurance) {
        this.endurance = endurance;
    }

    public void setIntelligence(int intelligence) {
        this.intelligence = intelligence;
    }

    public void setAttack(int attack) {
        this.attack = attack;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "This enemy is appearing: " + name  +
                ", health is " + health +
                ", strength is " + strength;
    }
}
```

EnemyList class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EnemyList {

    List<Entity> characters = new ArrayList<>();

    public void print()
    {
        for (Entity entity : characters)
        {
            System.out.println(entity.toString());

        }
    }

}
```

Mechanics Interface

```
interface Mechanics {

    boolean isDead();

    int damageDelt (int damage);

    //int levelup();


}
```

Comment: a question, each entity owns just one enemy? is it a 1-1 relationship?

Comment: I used the Entity class for inheritance.  For example, I made a Skeleton Class that extends off of Entity and Implements Mechanics. 

If I am understanding yes an entity is its own thing (like skeleton or troll) and adding them to a list

Comment: I mean, can there be two enemies within the same entity? So if I choose 2 enemies to fight, could they be from the same entity? (Two knights, etc..)

Comment: My apologies, yes they can.

Comment: No worries mate. Is your question how to make a loop that doesn't repeat the enemy to fight? Like, if i already fought the Knight, let's discard it for the next fight?

Comment: ya for now, I just need the base implementation for right now then Ill workk on it,  Just after working on it for so long my brain is fried and I am starting to confuse myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, will try to help here.

First of all, I think this is unnecessary:

```
    Integer[] array = new Integer[enemyList.characters.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));
```

You already have an `array`, contained in the `enemyList` instance, called `characters.`

Now let's say your user wants to fight with 5 enemies. To randomize the event, you shuffle the array first.

```
Collections.shuffle(enemyList.characters);
```

Assuming that `maxEnemies = 5` , let's go to the loop:

```
 boolean win = true;
 for (int i=0;i<maxEnemies;i++)
 {
    Entity enemy = enemyList.characters.get(i);
    String enemyName = enemy.getName();
    System.out.println("Fighting "+enemyName);
    //... your logic here
    if (character.isDead()) 
    {
       win=false;
       break;
    }
 }

 if (!win)
    System.out.println("You have been defeated! You are a disgrace to your family");
 else
    System.out.println("You've defeated "+maxEnemies+" bastards. You WON!
                        Tiger blood runs through your veins");
```

Note I moved the "fighting next enemy" text to the beginning of the loop clause, since the shown text would be incorrect when the last enemy has been defeated (*there will be no next enemy*).

As the index is based on your count (0-4), no monster will appear twice.

Note that you should validate the user input, deniying the input if the number of enemies he wills to fight is bigger than the number of Entities stored in the array. So the `input regarding number of entities to fight <= enemyList.characters.size`

I made some changes to the exit method as well, but feel free to change them so it fits your purposes. Instead of killing the thread, you could just call `break()` in order to finish the loop, and continue with the process the way you want.

Comment: So just to be sure, do I keep the loop:

for (Entity someEnemy : enemyList.characters)

Comment: The key is that it will be a maximum number of enemies to fight; So instead of iterating through all the enemies, just iterate through a count and inside that loop, get one Entity at each iteration

Comment: : for (Entity someEnemy : enemyList.characters) would be the correct approach if you need to iterate through all of them; But as you said, a user decides how many of them wants to fight. So change the logic of the loop (not for all entities, but for all choosenMaxNumber)

Comment: Gotcha now I understand, thank you for the clarification and help.

Comment: a pleasure to help. glad you could get what i was trying to say, sometimes I can't even understand my own statements

Comment: Just to clarify other mistake. Note that if you do:  for (int i = 0; i < enemyCount; i++) 
   for (Entity someEnemy : enemyList.characters) what you will get is every enemy showing "enemyCount" times. For example, if you have 10 enemies, and you declare enemyCount to 5, then 50 enemies will show (each one five times)

Comment: Ya I noticed that earlier when I was trying to figure it out.  I accidently print the whole list for enemyCount times.